# Java susbstring breaks after string validation

Tags: java, swing

I've searched around quite a bit for an answer to this, but with no luck.

I have this string:

```
String letter = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please insert the letter");
```

and this is a way of validating that only specific letters get in:

```
        while (!letter.toLowerCase().matches("a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please insert an appropriate letter");
            letter = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please insert the letter: ");       
        }
```

and when I try and get a substring like so:

```
   String letterString = letter.substring(0, 1);

   System.out.println(letterString);
```

This prints nothing, even if there is a correct value entered. Eclipse enters debug mode and the JOptionPane message box is closed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1) `substring(0)` is useless; the substring is the entire string.  2) I don't see where `letterGrade` is declared or assigned.

Comment: Surely there's a stack trace barfed up somewhere. Can you paste it for us to see?

Comment: You are "substringing" letterString and printing letterGrade...so....you know...

Comment: @dierre Ah, my mistake while pasting. In the code it's actually LetterString.

Comment: @rgettman Apologies, mistakes while pasting. Actual code is updated now.

Comment: @NRitH What's a stack trace?

Comment: Your code as it currently exists in the question works fine for me.  The JOptionPane calls do what they should, and the expected value is printed to the console.

Comment: I think you should use this regex: `"^[a-k]$"`, becouse you want to test the whole string. You can look for it at http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html#regex_starter

Comment: @IanMcLaird So it prints normally? What happens when you enter a wrong value?

Comment: @Vertex Thanks for the regex! Much more neat, I'll read the whole article!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pasted code works perfectly, as you can see from this running example. The error is somewhere else.

```
public class StringValidation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String letter = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please insert the letter");
        while (!letter.toLowerCase().matches("a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please insert an appropriate letter");
            letter = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please insert the letter: ");
        }
        String letterString = letter.substring(0, 1);
        System.out.println(letterString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you're completely right... It worked al right when I removed the validation, so I deduced it most probably is form there. Thanks a lot for your help and time, I'll go back and troubleshoot some other possibilities.